# Why is a directory I copied from my local machine not showing in the directory listing?

Tags: permissions, ssh, apache2

This is the chain of commands I ran:

1) Copy the local directory to the remote server:

`$ scp -r <directory> callum@<remote-server-ip>:`

2) Log into the remote server and move the directory to the public html directory:

`$ sudo mv <directory> /var/www/html`

3) From the command line I can see that `<directory>` is now listed at `/var/www/html`:

```
/var/www/html$ ls
<directory>  node-apps
```

When I visit the server IP in the browser, a directory listing is returned and only *node-apps* appears.

If, from the command line, I create a new directory or file, these **are** shown in the directory listing in the browser.

The user *callum* has sudo privileges and I have ssh-key authentication set up, and root login disabled.

Any ideas why my copied directory isn't showing up in the directory listing in the browser?

EDIT: running `ls -lsa` ouputs:

```
4 drwxrwx--- 9 callum callum 4096 Mar  8 12:26 <directory>
4 drwxrwxr-x 3 callum callum 4096 Jan 26 14:06 node-apps
```

Comment: Did you try to restart the web-server (in order to cause it to load the new data)?

Comment: what is the result of `ls -lsa` does both directories have the same permission?

Comment: The permission seem to be different - please see my edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to solve the problem you need to give access permission to the directory.

The following command should solve the problem:

```
sudo chmod 775 /var/www/html/<directory_name>
```

- sudo - execute as `root`
- chmod - change permission of the directory
- 755 - provides read/execute access to anyone

Note, you might also need to give access to the files inside the directory, using the following recursive chmod command:

```
sudo chmod -R 775 /var/www/html/<directory_name>
```

Same as above, with the additional paramater:

- -R - recursive